# Process HTML page without triggering internet connections

Tags: vba, autohotkey

`page.html` is saved website that has many java scripts (even when i disable JS in internet explorer options, page still manages to load trackers upon rendering).

Every time calling function `findElement()` my local proxy server that shows three request to tracking sites, total nine unnecessary requests for code below.

```
HTML := FileRead("page.html") 

findElement(HTML, findStr) {
    HTMLFile := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
    HTMLFile.write(HTML)
    DOMElements := HTMLFile .getElementsByTagName(findStr)
}

findElement(HTML, "div")
findElement(HTML, "a")    
findElement(HTML, "span")
```

My goal is to find elements on this page without triggering any internet connections, is there solution for this or i am forced to use regex to process HTML page?

Comment: Is the javascript necessary at all? Read the file, remove every `script` tag & its contents. Then do your thing…

Comment: @Dorian but to remove the script i still need to find it first so i end up using `.getElementsByTagName("script")` and it will trigger external calls, or how i remove it otherwise?

Comment: Parse the raw html file, remove `<script></script>` and everything in between